# Where can I find the MASTANI-2014 tutorial files?

Tags: reference-request, education

There was a two-week summer school on Density Functional Theory using Quantum ESPRESSO in the summer of 2014 organized by The Abdus Salam International Centre for Theoretical Physics (ICTP), jointly with the Indian Institute of Science Education and Research (IISER), Pune. It's called MASTANI - *MA*terial *S*imulations *T*heory *A*nd *N*umer*I*cs. I cannot find the presentation slides and tutorial files of this workshop.

The program's website: https://indico.ictp.it/event/a13246/ (working but does not have anything)

Tutorial files and slides: [http://sites.iiserpune.ac.in/~smr2626/talks-presentations.html](http://sites.iiserpune.ac.in/%7Esmr2626/talks-presentations.html) (the link is broken)

The Wayback machines has archived the sites but not every slides and files. Here is the archived link: [https://web.archive.org/web/20160414111506/http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~smr2626/talks-presentations.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414111506/http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/%7Esmr2626/talks-presentations.html)

If someone has access to all these files, could you share them somehow? Or can anyone reach to the organizers to let them know that the site is not working? From the content of their workshop, it seems promising.

Comment: Did you try writing to smr2626@ictp.it?

Comment: No, I haven't. That's a good idea. I am writing them right away even though I doubt anybody will be available to reply because the event has been completed almost 9 years ago!

Comment: @Camps, the email address is unreachable now. My mail got returned with an error of "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table".

Comment: @Earmen you could try writing on their social channels such as twitter, fb, LinkedIn and Insta. All the links are at the bottom of the website.

Comment: @VandanRevanur the social media is actually not associated with IISER but ICTP whereas the webpage is maintained by IISER. I have contacted several organizers in IISER through email. Also, from a different personal source I am promised to receive all the materials. I will upload/link it here as soon as I can get access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The webpage is still not working, and haven't gotten any reply from the organizers (several media have been attempted). However, I found a GitHub repository containing all the slides and tutorial files. This is the repository: **[DFT MASTANI School IISER Pune 2014](https://github.com/thepranab/DFT-MASTANI-School-IISER-Pune-2014)**. You can use [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414111506/http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/%7Esmr2626/talks-presentations.html) archived page as a table of content for the repository.